# How do I install Pecl Phar? (getting errors)

Tags: php, centos, pecl, phar

On Centos 6, php 5.5

I am trying to install the PHAR package with PECL. During the installation I get an "make failed" error:

```
creating libtool
appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config.h
running: make
/bin/sh /root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rootZdozvf/phar-2.0.0/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/root/tmp/pear/phar -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rootZdozvf/phar-2.0.0/include -I/root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rootZdozvf/phar-2.0.0/main -I/root/tmp/pear/phar -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /root/tmp/pear/phar/util.c -o util.lo
mkdir .libs
 cc -I. -I/root/tmp/pear/phar -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rootZdozvf/phar-2.0.0/include -I/root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rootZdozvf/phar-2.0.0/main -I/root/tmp/pear/phar -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /root/tmp/pear/phar/util.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/util.o
/root/tmp/pear/phar/util.c: In function ‘phar_mount_entry’:
/root/tmp/pear/phar/util.c:205: error: ‘struct _php_core_globals’ has no member named ‘safe_mode’
/root/tmp/pear/phar/util.c:205: error: ‘CHECKUID_CHECK_FILE_AND_DIR’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/root/tmp/pear/phar/util.c:205: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
/root/tmp/pear/phar/util.c:205: error: for each function it appears in.)
/root/tmp/pear/phar/util.c: In function ‘phar_find_in_include_path’:
/root/tmp/pear/phar/util.c:274: warning: assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type
/root/tmp/pear/phar/util.c: In function ‘phar_open_archive_fp’:
/root/tmp/pear/phar/util.c:854: error: ‘struct _php_core_globals’ has no member named ‘safe_mode’
/root/tmp/pear/phar/util.c:854: error: ‘CHECKUID_ALLOW_ONLY_FILE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/root/tmp/pear/phar/util.c: In function ‘phar_add_virtual_dirs’:
/root/tmp/pear/phar/util.c:2218: warning: assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type
make: *** [util.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

I am not sure why, but I went to PECL and saw that the PHAR package has some dependencies, I tried installing the first dependency listed, BZ2, but then I got another error:

```
Make sure that you run '/usr/local/bin/phpize' in the top level source directory of the module
```

And so I found this very [useful post](https://serverfault.com/questions/434157/phpize-cannot-find-config-m4-centos6-saprfc-install), which showed me how to manually download the package, put in the right place. But after running ./configure I just get a message telling me to re-intall BZ2.

And so I found out that I can run `pecl install --alldeps phar` to install all dependencies. I did that, and now I get the following error:

```
 cc -I. -I/root/tmp/pear/hash -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rootm2aHqA/hash-1.5/include -I/root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rootm2aHqA/hash-1.5/main -I/root/tmp/pear/hash -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /root/tmp/pear/hash/hash.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/hash.o
/root/tmp/pear/hash/hash.c:785: error: duplicate ‘static’
/root/tmp/pear/hash/hash.c:792: error: duplicate ‘static’
/root/tmp/pear/hash/hash.c:799: error: duplicate ‘static’
/root/tmp/pear/hash/hash.c:807: error: duplicate ‘static’
/root/tmp/pear/hash/hash.c:815: error: duplicate ‘static’
/root/tmp/pear/hash/hash.c:822: error: duplicate ‘static’
/root/tmp/pear/hash/hash.c:828: error: duplicate ‘static’
/root/tmp/pear/hash/hash.c:835: error: duplicate ‘static’
/root/tmp/pear/hash/hash.c:842: error: duplicate ‘static’
/root/tmp/pear/hash/hash.c:848: error: duplicate ‘static’
make: *** [hash.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

**I would appreciate any help getting phar installed. Thanks!**

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. As it turns out, PHAR was not compiled with PHP, and to get it to work I had to recompile php with the PHAR package enabled.